# About the pimpl syntax

Tags: c++, pimpl-idiom

I have a question about the C++ usage used in the pimpl syntax.

First, why is it not necessary to write `pimpl( new impl )` as `pimpl( new my_class::impl )`

Second, why is the lifetime of `new impl` extended even though it is a temporary object?

```
//my_class.h
class my_class {
   //  ... all public and protected stuff goes here ...
private:
   class impl; unique_ptr<impl> pimpl; // opaque type here
}
```

```
// my_class.cpp
class my_class::impl {  // defined privately here
  // ... all private data and functions: all of these
  //     can now change without recompiling callers ...
};
my_class::my_class(): pimpl( new impl )
{
  // ... set impl values ...
}
```

Comment: Where do you get the idea `new impl` is a temporary? You allocated it from the heap and *just* stored it in a member variable that manages it for the life of the class.

Comment: To 'First', everything in a member of an out of class implementation is available to name resolution once the compiler makes it past `my_class::`, and that includes the leading `my_class::` for the ctor and dtor. Therefore, `my_class::impl` is not longer required; you can use `impl` in that context, including as you are in that member initialization list

Comment: You are already in the scope of `my_class` as this is the body of a member function, hence no need to qualify class members. `new impl` is a pointer of type `impl*`. Its lifetime is not extended. It is being used to initialise `pimpl` and then it dies  The `impl` that it points at is not a temporary, it is a heap-allocated object.

Comment: offtipic: it is not a syntax. It is an idiom or design pattern.

Comment: You are did `using namespace std;` in header (the only case when you can skip `std::` before `unique_ptr`)! This is BIG mistake do not do it. Even having `using namespace std;` in cpp file is considered a bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First, why is it not necessary to write pimpl( new impl ) as pimpl( new my_class::impl )

Scope. When constructor is defined you are inside a cope of a class, so [name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup) is able to find it without problems.

> Second, why is the lifetime of new impl extended even though it is a temporary object?

You are passing temporary pointer to as constructor argument of `std::unique_ptr<impl>` so value is consumed by a field `pimpl`. `impl` value s not temporary since it is created on a heap, control of its lifetime was passed to smart pointer.

**Extra:**
You did `using namespace std;` in header (the only case when you can skip `std::` before `unique_ptr`)! This is BIG mistake do not do it. This will impact dangerously all sources which will include this header. You can have symbol ambiguity error because of that.

Even having `using namespace std;` in cpp file is [considered a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1387438).

Answer (score 2):

**First:** In your constructor the expression `new impl` indeed is a temporary object, but it is immediately passed to the `pimpl` member which is not a temporary. The `std::unique_ptr` type stores the pointer passed to it and holds on to it until it is destroyed or moved. And the member is not destroyed until the `my_class` object is destroyed.

Also, consider using [`std::make_unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) instead of `new`.

**Second:** You don't have to write `my_class::impl` because you are in a member function of `my_class`, so name resolution looks [not only at namespace scope but also at class scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope). So, `impl` can be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The `new impl` is not temporary because it's not a variable.

It is an expression, which

1. is evaluated during your `my_class::pimpl` object member construction,
2. its side effect is creation of an `impl` object (whose lifetime is controlled, not automatic, because it's not a local automatic variable),
3. and which returns a pointer to the newly created *anonymous* `impl` object.

The expression is used as an initializer to the `pimpl` member of the `my_class` object being constructed, so the returned pointer is passed as an initializing value to `pimpl` and gets stored in it. This allows your `my_class` object to control the life time of the `impl` object.

The life time of the `pimpl` pointer variable is obviously the same as its owning `my_class` object's life time, however the life time of the pointed `impl` object depends on your `my_class` logic:

1. it may keep it until its own end and get it deleted during its own destruction,
2. it may `replace()` it with another one at will
3. or `release()` the `pimpl`, `delete` the `impl` object and work without any when no longer necessary...
4. It might even release the object and *not* delete it, for example to transfer the ownership to another object – or just abandon it, which causes a memory leak (and which is usually a serious error!)